# Android layout not as expected

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

So I am a beginner at layouts in Android and I am learning `RelativeLayout`. I am attempting to make the following:

[image]

However, all I get in my virtual device is the name field taking up 100% of the space (width and height).
[image]

Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/root">
    <EditText android:id="@+id/name" 
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:hint = "Name"/>
    <EditText android:id="@+id/phone" 
        android:layout_below="@id/name" 
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
        android:layout_weight="0.4" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="0dp" 
        android:hint="Phone" />
    <EditText android:id="@+id/email" 
        android:layout_below="@id/phone" 
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
        android:layout_weight="0.4" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="0dp" 
        android:hint="Email" />
    <EditText android:id="@+id/dob" 
        android:layout_below="@id/email" 
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
        android:layout_weight="0.4" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="0dp" 
        android:hint="D.O.B." />
    <EditText android:id="@+id/address" 
        android:layout_below="@id/phone" 
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/dob"
        android:layout_weight="0.6" 
        android:layout_height="0dp" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:hint="Address" />
    <Button android:id="@+id/submit" 
        android:layout_weight="1.0" 
        android:layout_below="@id/address" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:layout_width="0dp" 
        android:text="Submit"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**What is going wrong?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the xml for your output.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/root"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:hint="Name" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/phone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true
        android:layout_weight="-10"
        android:hint="Phone" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/phone"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        android:hint="Email" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/dob"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/email"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        android:hint="D.O.B." />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/address"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/phone"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/dob"
        android:layout_weight="0.6"
        android:hint="Address" />
</RelativeLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/submit"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"                
    android:text="Submit" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Why did you nest it in a `LinearLayout` ?? :-)

Comment: For making `orientation` as vertical. `RelativeLayout` does not support `orientation` property. As you can see I have only added middle `EditText` in `RelativeLayout` so for designing it for your purpose. Top `EditText` and bottom `Button` can be automatically arranged by orientation. If you change the orientation of your mobile device from portrait to landscape then also it will not break. Trying doing some tweak with this xml, it will you better idea.

Comment: and what does the `-10` weight do ?

Answer (score 1):

Change the layout_height for the name element to:
`android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

Comment: What wrong did `match_parent` do ? AFAIK, it only means "however much the parent assigns".

Comment: Actually matches parent size. See [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html#MATCH_PARENT)

Comment: Not a trick - what you should use. Also layout_weights are for linear layouts only, so specifying values of 0dp is unlikely to help your layout. (and should use dip for device independence if specifying a fixed size)

Comment: I didnt know that weights are `LinearLayout` only .. thanks for pointing that out :)

Answer (score 1):

Change your Layout XML to the above:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:hint="Name" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/name"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/address"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.6"
        android:hint="Address" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        android:weightSum="3" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/phone"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="Phone" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="Email" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/dob"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="D.O.B." />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/submit"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="Submit" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope that helps:)